# Execute code when app reopens

Tags: objective-c, ios, multitasking

I have a Single View Application. When I hit the home button and ‘minimise’ the application I want to be able to execute code when the user reopens it.

For some reason viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear do not execute when I minimise and reopen the application.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance
sAdam

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either execute code in the app delegate in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

or register to observe the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification and execute your code in response.

There is also the notification `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and the method `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` in the app delegate.

---

To hook up notifications add this at an appropriate point

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                       selector:@selector(didBecomeActive:)
                                           name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                         object:nil];
```

Define a the corresponding method

```
- (void)didBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Then don't forget to remove yourself an observer at an appropriate point

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

**Discussion**

You most likely only want your viewController to respond to events whilst it is the currently active view controller so a good place to register for the notifications would be `viewDidLoad` and then a good place to remove yourself as an observer would be `viewDidUnload`

If you are wanting to run the same logic that occurs in your `viewDidAppear:` method then abstract it into another method and have `viewDidAppear:` and the method that responds to the notification call this new method.

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly. NSNotification centre looks powerful! Will be time well spent looking at this in more detail. Thanks!

Comment: It certainly is powerful but it can also be used poorly creating a nasty unmaintainable spiders web of logic, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is because since Apple implemented "Multitasking", apps are completely reloaded when you start them again, just as if you had never closed them. Because of this, there is no reason for viewDidAppear to be called.

You could either implement

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

and do there what ever you want. Or you register for the notification `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` in your view controller. Do this in viewDidLoad:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myAppWillEnterForeground) 
    name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

And of course implement the specified selector and do there what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the answer by @Paul.s performs the OP request since registering `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` will be executed twice:

1. When launching the app
2. When application goes into the background

A better practice will be to decouple those events into 2 different [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class):

1. [UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification):

> Posted when the app becomes active.
>   An app is active when it is receiving events. An active app can be said to have focus. It gains focus after being launched, loses focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked, and gains focus when the device is unlocked.

Which basically means that all logic related to "when application launched for the first time"

2. [UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification):

> Posted shortly before an app leaves the background state on its way to becoming the active app.

### Conclusion

This way we can create a design that will perform both algorithms but as a decoupled way:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourMethodName1) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourMethodName2) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This because you don't redraw your view. Use **applicationWillEnterForeground** in the AppDelegate instead. This should work fine for you.